# Drawing objects behind circle except the ones behind 'background'

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, draw

**Situation:** I have a canvas on an Android game, I have some objects (I will keep it as simple as possible):`World`(where are storaged all `Laser` and `Block` objects), `Block and Laser`. I can draw all this objects in the canvas.

I would like to 'hide' them behind a black 'background', and then draw a blurry 'transparent' circle, so all objects are hidden behind the black background, except the objects behing the circle.

I have thought about it, but I can't think of an approach to do this.

**Images:**

This is my actual situation:

[image: Actual]

This is the expected:
[image: Expected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
    public void drawBitmapsInCanvas(Canvas c){
        c.drawBitmap(block, new Rect(/*coordinates here*/), new Rect(/*More coordinates*/),null);
        c.drawBitmap(block2, new Rect(/*coordinates here*/), new Rect(/*More coordinates*/),null);
        c.drawBitmap(laser, new Rect(/*coordinates here*/), new Rect(/*More coordinates*/),null);
        c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);//this hides everything under your black background.
        c.drawBitmap(circle, new Rect(/*coordinates here*/), new Rect(/*More coordinates*/),null);
    }
```

If you want transparency:

```
    Paint paint =new Paint();
    paint.setARGB(120,0,0,0); //for the "120" parameter, 0 is completely transparent, 255 is completely opaque.
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    c.drawBitmap(bmp,Rect r,Rect rr, paint);
```

or if you are trying to change the opacity of individual pixels, the approach is a bit more complicated (I have not tested the code, but you get the gist of it):

```
public static final Bitmap getNewBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int circleCenterX,
int circleCenterY,int circleRadius){
    //CIRCLE COORDINATES ARE THE DISTANCE IN RESPECT OF (0,0) of the bitmap
    //, not (0,0) of the canvas itself. The circleRadius is the circle's radius.
    Bitmap temp=bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    int[]pixels = new int[temp.getWidth()*temp.getHeight()];
    temp.getPixels(pixels,0 ,temp.getWidth(),0,0,temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight());
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<pixels.length;i++){
        int alpha=Color.alpha(pixels[i]);
        if(alpha!=0&&!((Math.pow(counter/temp.getWidth()-circleCenterY,2.0)+
        Math.pow(counter%temp.getWidth()-circleCenterX,2.0))<Math.pow(circleRadius,2.0))){
        //if the pixel itself is not completely transparent and the pixel is NOT within range of the circle,
        //set the Alpha value of the pixel to 0.
            pixels[i]=Color.argb(0,Color.red(pixels[i]),Color.green(pixels[i]),Color.blue(pixels[i]));
        }
        counter++;
    }
    temp.setPixels(pixels,0, temp.getWidth(),0,0,temp.getWidth(),temp.getHeight());
    return temp;
}
```

and then draw `temp.`

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to ask, so you may have to modify as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you try the second answer of qwertyuiop5040, you will get a ver low - perfomance when you try to apply it to a large image. Let's say a 1000*800 pixels image. Then you will have a loop:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000*800; i++)
```

Comment: You're right. But typically you don't edit images this size or anywhere near this size: they tend to be backgrounds, and even most backgrounds can be scaled down.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an image that's a black rectangle with a transparent hole in it. The hole would be the circle that you can see through, and the image would be rendered over the spot you want to be visible. Then, you can draw four black rectangles around the image to cover the rest of the screen.